# Quaternion get a minus sign after full rotation

Tags: animation

I'm making a rolling animation of my character.

After rolling 360 degrees, when the character gets to its initial pose, the rotation quaternion goes from (1,0,0,0) to (-1,0,0,0)

That's a known "feature" of quaternions: q and -q represent the same rotation. However, when the quaternion rotates 360 degrees, q becomes -q. you need to rotate 720 degrees to get +q again.

It causes trouble in interpolating between frames. the character will erroneously rotate 360 degrees if I copy the initial pose to the last frame. it is because one is interpolation between (1,0,0,0) and (-1,0,0,0)

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Hello. A solution might be to set a keyframe with the rotation to 180° at the middle of your animation that way the interpolation doesn't go the wrong way

Answer (score 4):

When a quaternion keyframe causes troubles because it's inverted, you can use this operator to flip it's values without affecting its orientation.

[image]

Comment: Wow.. and there I was, about to launch an essay.. :D

Comment: I was worried about cycling animation. at the end frame the quaternion is inverted. That might cause trouble when mixing with another animation in the NLA